# Django-crontab - ERROR: sh: line 1: /usr/bin/crontab: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, cron

I followed the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/)

In my django project specific venv (myproject/venv) I installed django-crontab[0.7.1]
using command:

```
(venv) pip3 install django-crontab
```

added to settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 ...

'django_crontab',

)

CRONTAB_COMMAND_SUFFIX = '2>&1'

CRONJOBS = [
('*/1 * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['my_command'])
]
```

Next when I run `python manage.py crontab add` I get Error:

```
(venv) python manage.py crontab add
/bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/crontab: No such file or directory
adding cronjob: (b27648b2dab947d53fe7e8c052bcd9a7) -> ('*/1 * * * *', 
'django.core.management.call_command', ['my_command'])
sh: line 1: /usr/bin/crontab: No such file or directory
```

But I checked manually /usr/bin/ and I see a file named crontab is present.

After that when I run `python manage.py crontab show` there is no job added.

At this point I don't know what should I do. Need Help.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : Ok i think i understand the problem. The script is running in an virtual environment, so it can't access cron. I don't know exactly solve this problem but i think you can check the solution give by this page : https://codeinthehole.com/tips/running-django-cronjobs-within-a-virtualenv/

Alternative solution, just run the script without Venv.

---

Cron seems to be not installed on your system.

Try this (if you are on Ubuntu or any other Debian-based distrib) :

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install cron
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cron`
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree`
`Reading state information... Done`
`cron is already the newest version (3.0pl1-136ubuntu1).`

Comment: Yes, i just noticed you already check, i'm editing my post. Did you try to run with sudo your script ?

Comment: like this?

`(venv) sudo python manage.py crontab add`
`sh: sudo: command not found`

Comment: The problem seems to be the virtual environment where the script running. I just added to my post a link with a potential solution. If you want an alternative way, you can test to just running the script without venv.

Comment: I am not able to run outside also. Can you give me an example of full command to run in terminal (without venv activated). note: the `django-crontab` package is installed in venv only.

Comment: I wanted to use `django-crontab` as he did [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jaESVKqUs4&t=287s)